# Echo cancellation when using multiple swfs in the same page

Tags: flash, apache-flex, video-streaming, video-conferencing

We are building a video conferencing solution using multiple swfs in the same web page. Each representing one participant (one them is a publisher). The issue is that when one participant is on a laptop, the others voices are echoed via his microphone to the other speakers. While i am aware of getEnhancedMicrophone function in flash, it does not seem to work. It seems to work if the sender and receiver video/audio are on the same SWF. Unfortunately we designed the solution in such a way that each participant is a separate SWF. Now is there a way to reduce the echo ie., one SWFs' mic picks up the speaker output from say 3 participants ?

Answer (score 0):

Echo cancellation isn't going to work across multiple swf instances. Serve the same swf to each computer for each of your users and open multiple netconnection instances for each user from the same swf.